# Overhead of LXD

Tags: lxc, containers, lxd

Question for server structure here.

Is the overhead for LXD small enough to use it for per-process containers?
E.G if I have a LAMP stack, media server, game server, etc. is it viable to split each of these into separate containers and how big will the cpu usage difference be between that and running them all as processes on the one normal server?

Obviously the benefits from a management/access standpoint are big, just wondering how much of a drain this would put on CPU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LXD doesn't imply significant overhead at all -- to the degree that you don't need to care about it. You can think of it as a process manager. The primary source of overhead will be in your container images, which you will need to ensure are as small as possible while still accomplishing the task at hand.

It's quite easy to have large inefficient images, and it can be difficult to have small purpose-built images. Starting from a small base helps.